# FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory - LIGHTHOUSE

Tags: javascript, node.js, out-of-memory, lighthouse

I'm trying to use lighthouse from javascript like this:

```
var lighthouse = require('lighthouse');
var chromeLauncher = require('lighthouse/chrome-launcher/chrome-launcher');
var ReportGenerator = require('lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generator')

var url = 'http://localhost:8080';
var flags = {output: 'json'};
var config = null;

  chromeLauncher.launch().then(function(chrome) {
    flags.port = chrome.port;
    return lighthouse(url, flags, config).then(function(results) {
      return chrome.kill().then(function() { return results; })
    });
  }).then(function(results) { 
      html = new ReportGenerator().generateReportHtml(results);
      console.log(html); 
    });
```

However it seems that generating the html programmatically is causing node to crash OOM

```
$ node index2.js

<--- Last few GCs --->

   69281 ms: Mark-sweep 1250.1 (1438.1) -> 1250.1 (1438.1) MB, 793.8 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
   69998 ms: Mark-sweep 1250.1 (1438.1) -> 1250.1 (1438.1) MB, 716.6 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [scavenge might not succeed].
   70795 ms: Mark-sweep 1250.1 (1438.1) -> 1265.1 (1422.1) MB, 797.4 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
   71556 ms: Mark-sweep 1265.1 (1422.1) -> 1280.7 (1422.1) MB, 760.9 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x1940ecbcf781 <JS Object>
    1: stringify [native json.js:178] [pc=0x2037a6e19a57] (this=0x1940ecbc92a1 <a JSON with map 0x26acd5f09b09>,E=0x9b9ceafc99 <an Object with map 0x1601799c0a11>,F=0x1940ecb04381 <undefined>,S=0x1940ecb04381 <undefined>)
    2: arguments adaptor frame: 1->3
    3: generateReportHtml [/Users/arbi/Projects/test-lighthouse/node_modules/lighthouse/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generato...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewRawTwoByteString(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::IncrementalStringBuilder::Extend() [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<true>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Result v8::internal::BasicJsonStringifier::Serialize_<false>(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
13: v8::internal::Runtime_BasicJSONStringify(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/Users/arbi/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/node]
14: 0x2037a65092a7
[1]    11901 abort      node index2.js
```

Outputting simply [lighthouse](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse) report in json seems to work fine, but I need to be able to generate html too.

Also increase mem seems to fix the problem

```
$ node --max-old-space-size=16000 index2.js
```

Any idea how for a walk around this issue without just adding memory?

Comment: Looks like your heap allocation went above 800MB... that's quite a lot of memory and suggests that you have a memory leak somewhere in your code.

Comment: I guess it's the way lighthouse generates the html report may have issues https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/blob/branch2.x/lighthouse-core/report/v2/report-generator.js#L74-L88

Comment: It looks like it's buffering the entire JSON string in memory and performing a string replace. There are some libraries capable of stream transforms on JSON, but finding one to stream this particular transformation (operating on a few kilobytes of data at a time) is likely to be difficult. I'm not familiar with lighthouse or I'd give more concrete advice.

Comment: can you advice on a streaming option, I could use alternatively to what lighthouse is currently doing?